# Can `match` in Racket have patterns with variables from an outer scope?

Tags: scope, scheme, pattern-matching, racket

Consider the following example:

```
#lang racket

(match '(cat . doge)
  [`(,a . ,b)
   (match b
     [a #t]
     [_ #f])]
  [_ "Not a pair"])
```

This is what I might write if I wanted to match pairs where the head and tail are the same. This doesn't work though because the second `a` is bound as a new variable (and matches anything). Are there any pattern forms which allow me to use the previously bound `a` from the outer scope?

I know this can be achieved in the following way

```
(match* ('cat 'doge)
  [(a a) #t]
  [(_ _) #f])
```

but I still would like to know if there is a way to get that variable from the outer scope (or if there is a reason for not doing so, like some potential name collision problem or something).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use [`==`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fmatch..rkt%29._~3d~3d%29%29):

```
(match '(cat . doge)
  [`(,a . ,b)
   (match b
     [(== a) #t]
     [_      #f])]
  [_ "Not a pair"])
```

Due to the placement in the docs, [`==`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fmatch..rkt%29._~3d~3d%29%29) is easy to overlook.

Comment: Also easy to overlook is `#:when`. For example, the clause could be `[(cons a b) #:when (eq? a b) #t]`. Of course `==` is simpler in this example.