# How do you match hash-table against the value of a local variable?

Tags: pattern-matching, racket

```
> (define h #hash((a . 11) (b . 0)))
> (define (f h key)
    (match h
      [(hash-table (key value)) value]
      [_ 'do-something-else]))
> (f h 'a)
'do-something-else  ;; expect 11
```

How should I modify the `match` pattern so the function above returns the same as `(hash-ref h key 'do-something-else)`?

One problem seems to be that `match` is auto-quoting `key`, so that it literally matches `'key` rather than the value of the `key` local variable. A second problem is that `match hash-table` seems to want to match the entire hash table rather than just one key-value pair.

Comment: To clarify: The point is not to duplicate `hash-ref`. This is just a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). More realistically, I'd have multiple match clauses followed by a catch-all at the end. In effect, "destructure the first key/value pair that matches". Or who knows? There's no telling when I might want to match a local variable rather than a literal.

Comment: See also [Can `match` in Racket have patterns with variables from an outer scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29978583/can-match-in-racket-have-patterns-with-variables-from-an-outer-scope)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How to duplicate the behavior of `hash-ref`

To duplicate the behavior of `hash-ref`, you need to do two things:

(1) Use a `key` pattern that only matches things that are *equal* to the value of the argument `key`. You can do this with the [`==` pattern](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html?q=%3D%3D#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fmatch..rkt%29._~3d~3d%29%29):

```
(hash-table ((== key) value))
```

(2) Match hash tables where there are other entries other than `key`. You can do this by adding `_ ...` to match the other entries.

```
(hash-table ((== key) value) _ ...)
```

In context:

```
(define (f h key)
  (match h
    [(hash-table ((== key) value) _ ...) value]
    [_ 'do-something-else]))
```

Makes `(f h key)` behave like `(hash-ref h key 'do-something-else)`.

#### Why your first attempt didn't work

Your pattern:

```
(hash-table (key value))
```

Does *not* autoquote the `key` so that it literally matches `'key`. Instead it matches any hash table that has only one entry:

```
> (match (hash 'anything-goes 11)
    [(hash-table (key value)) value]
    [_ 'do-something-else])
11
```

That's because `key` is interpreted as a pattern, and an identifier as a pattern matches anything. You can see this more clearly if you name it to something else and use it in the body:

```
> (define (f h key-arg)
    (match h
      [(hash-table (key-pat value))
       (printf "key-arg = ~v\n" key-arg)
       (printf "key-pat = ~v\n" key-pat)
       value]))
> (f (hash 'anything-goes 11) 'a)
key-arg = 'a
key-pat = 'anything-goes
11
```

When you write an identifier pattern that "happens" to have the same name as a local variable, it *shadows* it, just like this example:

```
> (let ([x "local variable"])
    (match (list 1 2 3)
      [(list 1 2 x)
       x]))
 3
```

The `x` in the pattern matches anything, so it's matched against the `3`. The pattern shadows the `x`, so when the body uses `x`, it's referring to the `3`, and not the local variable. The local variable was never actually used because of this shadowing.

Comment: Thank you! I'd been staring and staring at the table [here](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html?q=match#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fmatch..rkt%29._match%29%29) and not finding a way—because that's not where it was! :) And thanks for straightening out my false theory about autoquoting. I'm glad to see that `==` is so simple and general (thanks to its optional second argument).

Comment: It's hidden in the grammer for `pattern` where it says `derived-pattern`, since `==` is defined outside of the "core" match form. However, from a user's perspective this shouldn't matter very much, so [this pull request](https://github.com/racket/racket/pull/2145) has proposed to add `==` to the match grammar to make it more discoverable.